# Native image building process is frozen in Quarkus

Tags: hibernate, docker, quarkus

The complete codes is hosted on my [github](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample).

When I ran `docker-compose up` to run the application, and it will build the project and in docker container. But when I saw the following messages, it is frozen and no further progress. I have waited it for 3o minutes.

```sh
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] Running Quarkus native-image plugin on OpenJDK 64-Bit GraalVM CE 19.1.1
[INFO] [io.quarkus.creator.phase.nativeimage.NativeImagePhase] /opt/graalvm/bin/native-image -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager --initialize-at-build-time= -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar demo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https --enable-all-security-services -H:-SpawnIsolates -H:+JNI --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace
[demo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:92]    classlist:  46,544.50 ms
[demo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:92]        (cap):   6,189.27 ms
[demo-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:92]        setup:  14,789.15 ms
12:15:35,728 INFO  [org.hib.Version] HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.4.Final}
12:15:35,872 INFO  [org.hib.ann.com.Version] HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
12:15:36,050 INFO  [org.hib.dia.Dialect] HHH000400: Using dialect: io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.dialect.QuarkusPostgreSQL95Dialect
12:15:36,207 INFO  [org.hib.val.int.uti.Version] HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.0.Alpha6
12:15:51,382 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] JBoss Threads version 3.0.0.Beta5
12:16:01,451 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO version 3.7.2.Final
12:16:03,196 INFO  [com.arj.ats.arjuna] ARJUNA012170: TransactionStatusManager started on port 44099 and host 127.0.0.1 with service com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.recovery.ActionStatusService
12:16:03,275 INFO  [org.xni.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.2.Final
```

Docker ps result:

```sh
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
633648bc80fe        e5e7016613b4        "/bin/sh -c 'mvn cle…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          8080/tcp            quirky_goldberg
```

Comment: seems like it container log, your container is running? verify using `docker ps` or better to post docker build log starting from `FROM quay.io/quarkus/centos-quarkus-maven:19.1.1 AS build`

Comment: Got an exception in the running console. `12:16:03,275 INFO  [org.xni.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.2.Final

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "native-image pid watcher"` Maybe I have to set a JAVA_OPTS env.

Comment: I just tried the example and it worked just fine on my machine. Looks like a resource issue on the hardware you are using. Make sure you give docker plenty of memory to work with

Comment: Got it work by increasing the memory size.

Comment: @Hantsy mind adding you solution as an answer to make it easier for future readers to easily find what you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a Docker toolbox under Windows 10, when creating a docker machine, the mem size is 512M by default. as suggested by @geoand, after simply increasing the memory size of VirtualBox, the problem was resolved.